# Can not remove angularcli on ubuntu

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu

i want to reinstall angularcli because

```
➜  Angular ng serve          
node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
```

it gives error like this when on project folder.

to remove, i do those

```
root@caner:/home/caner# npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
up to date in 0.036s
root@caner:/home/caner# npm cache clean
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-12-16T13_38_28_855Z-debug.log
root@caner:/home/caner# npm uninstall -g angular-cli
up to date in 0.034s
root@caner:/home/caner# npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

up to date in 0.041s
```

and i did both, verify and force, in different times

```
root@caner:/home/caner# npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.011s
root@caner:/home/caner# npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
```

but still it shows version of ng:

```
    root@caner:/home/caner# ng -v

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.1
Node: 9.2.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
...
root@caner:/h
```

so, that is why i think i cant remove it.

how can i remove?

ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Try to run `which ng` and see where binary is stored

Comment: So now you can't call angular-cli, right? If not try the same command again but instead of deleting try running `ls -la` for a given path to determine where it links to.

Comment: no i can call angular but i cant do this `➜  hello-world ng serve          
node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
➜  hello-world 
`

Comment: I'm assuming `npm install` didn't help, right?

Comment: yes. now `You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.
` this